# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined node.js filesystem

Tags: node.js, string, http, fs

I have this script here, upon loading the page, it should first load a header html boilerplate, some dynamic paragraphs, and end the request with a footer html boiler plate. Both Boilerplates come from external files.

After testing, I am receiving:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/user_code/index.js:20:23)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:367:13)**

My understanding was that I needed **.toString()** to ensure that what was loaded from the external files were buffered as strings.

```
exports.request = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

        fs.readFile('/public/templates/header-template.html', function(_err, data) {
            res.write(data.toString());
            console.log('Header Loaded');
        });

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
        var txt = '<p>Thanks <b>' + q.firstname + ' ' + q.lastname + '</b>. An email has been sent to <b>' + q.email + '</b> with details about your request.';
        res.write(txt);

        fs.readFile('/public/templates/footer-template.html', function(_err, data) {
            res.end(data.toString());
            console.log('Footer Loaded');
        });

    });
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the encoding to `toString()` to convert from a Buffer.

```
data.toString('utf8');
```

Additionally, it seems your variable `data` is not defined, so perfhaps your file doesn't exists. Capture the error and see what's wrong:

```
if(_err){
   console.error(_err);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try the above. This does work when only loading one file, and using `res.end` instead of `res.write`.

Does it matter that I used `data` in both `fs.readfile` sections? Should I set the sections to use different variables like `data1` and `data2`?

Comment: I have got this kind of error. because populate i have given upper case p.. but i should be lowercase.. hope this helps..

Comment: This answer helped me, coming out of 3 solid days of node.js debugging.  Thanks, man!